# How solved this problem... Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::sent()

Tags: php, laravel

I try to send mails from my UserController but I am getting an exception.

### Error massage

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail::sent()

### My code

**UserController:**

```php
Mail::to($user->email)->sent(new VarificationEmail($user));
```

**MailController:**

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('Email.verification')
    ->with([
        'uname' => $this->user->uname,
        'token' => $this->user->email_verification_token,
    ])
    ->bcc('pmsaidur@gmail.com')
    ->subject('Test');
}
```

Comment: You should always add the version your working with ;-) Somehow Symfony dose not know the method and and most likely the class. The might be something wrong with your dependency injection. Maybe it will help if you post the full classes Mail and User controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. It should be `send()` not `sent()`:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VarificationEmail($user));
```